# materalize autocomplete scroll issue

Tags: javascript, material-design, materialize

Hi I am using materal design framework for a autocomplete functionality. the problem is that when i type something in input file drop-down list is coming and i have set max-height and overflow scroll so it autocomplete list should scroll. problem is that when i start scrolling in scrollbar it automatically select any value from list. In mobile view when starting scroll then it select any value while scrolling or on touch. so basically scrolling issue. I have search for this solution on internet but not found some suitable solution. Can anyone help in regarding this?

Comment: I am also attaching a fiddle for reference. http://jsfiddle.net/Vtn5Y/1546/